# Swift: Extra Argument "progressblock" in call

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mbprogresshud

I'm having problems realising exactly why I am getting the error quoted in the question title when trying to implement a progress timer on my block.

```
func uploadImage(imageData: NSData!) {

    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "\(PFUser.currentUser().username)'s Avatar", data: imageData)

    // Show the HUD to prompt user of upload
    hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar
    hud.labelText = "Changing Image..."

    // Upload the image
    imageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        // Check there was no error, begin handling the file upload
        // trimmed out un-necessary code

        }, progressBlock: { (amountDone: Int32) -> Void in
            self.hud.progress = amountDone/100 as Float
    })
}
```

If I remove the line `self.hud.progress = amountDone/100 as Float` everything works as I'd expect, however putting anything within the `progressBlock` causes my application to crash.

I'm following a [Parse tutorial for uploading images](https://parse.com/tutorials/saving-images), only difference is I am working with Swift so I am needing to convert from Objective-C, however I can't see why this would make a huge difference in the syntax for constructing the second block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is casting issue.

You need to cast `amountDone` variable in to `Float` or `CGFloat` from `Int32`.

```
var flotAmount = Float(amountDone)
```

Check type of `self.hud.progress` if it is `Float` than use

```
self.hud.progress = Float(flotAmount/100)
```

And if it is CGFloat then use below line:

```
self.hud.progress = CGFloat(flotAmount/100)
```

Comment: You're totally right, I thought `as Float` would do the same to my expression - my bad...thanks Kampai